# Scale div and shrink its dom size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I have an embedded tweet.
I find them too big so I'm trying to scale them down.

I apply 50% scale transform on the tweet div itself and it works just fine.

The problem is, the parent div remains twice as large as it is now necessary.

Setting height: 50% sounds like an straightforward solution but it doesn't work. Only absolute numbers force it to shrink.

Due to nature of embeded tweets I cannot know the height of the element beforehand and I am unable to intercept when they are loaded (it takes a while so the size of the div changes several times until all elements are loaded)

How can I force the size of an element to be 50%?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to fix:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="tweet_embed">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><a href="https://twitter.com/futureshift/status/1502708454791778307?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a></blockquote>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
  </div>
  <div>There's too much white space above this text</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
}

.tweet_embed {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 80px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/noximo/pen/KKZKWZp

Comment: where your code?

Comment: I don't really have any right now, apart from applying transform: scale(0.5) onto embeded tweet

Comment: I've added some basic code that illustrates what I need

Comment: is it necessary nessary for you to use scale? It is not a good pratice to use scale in your example since you can;t use css `vh`, `max-content` ....

Comment: I've edited the code pen to actually load tweet. I cannot style the tweet directly as that would be quite complex and could change at any minute. Scaling it down is fast and easy but it leaves empty whitespace behind.

Comment: I post an a answer and as my answer states, try to remove the space is more complex solutiom

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting desired width for your container division and setting the width of the inner div to 100%?

The snippet below has a container div (black border and 5px padding) sized to 200px width (height is set only because I don't have content to stretch it) . Inside is the content div where your tweet markup would go (background colour set yellow), it is sized to 100% width to constrained by the container. Again, height will take care of itself when your content is added, it's set to 100% so you can see it.

Aplologies if I misunderstand your problem.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tweet {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tweet">
  tweet markup
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use fixed sizes because I don't know them in advance. The tweet that is getting embedded can have a reply or an image so it may vary wildly in size.

Comment: @Noximo I'm confused as to why you need to shrink the content if you don't care what size it occupies on the page. My set heights may have confused you so I've edited my answer, you don't need to know the dimensions of the content, just what width of the page you want it to occupy when rendered.

Comment: I do care about it's size, but I do have little control over it. Tweets that get embeded are simply too big. I want to make them smaller. But since I have no to little control over their html and css, I simply make the whole tweet scaled to 50%.
But that leaves a lot of empty whitespace underneath. I've added example to my question.

Comment: @Noximo I've poked around in the markup twitter delivers to your codepen and have discovered the following: The tweet panel is styled to occupy 100% width of its bounding element, up to a maximum of 550px, and it will not shrink below 250px wide. You really only need to delete your scale styles (infact get rid of the tweet_embed class entirely) and set the styles of the content class to have a suitable width in pixels (say 300px) or a width of 100% with max-width set to a pixel value (thus allowing a degree of responsiveness). The result is similar to your codepen, without the white space.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose and only be allowed to use css `transform:scale`, the answer is no (I mean no simple and direct solution because css `scale` is only a visual effect and doesn't change the element height and width really.

Notice that it is always not a good practice to give scale to child element only since you have to be considered the space problem.

see the js code I put, it width and height doesn't change, so the actual height/width for .tweet_embed it still the same before is scaled.

```js
console.log(window.innerHeight,window.innerWidth)
//Get width and height value for .tweet_embed 
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.tweet_embed')).getPropertyValue('width'))

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.tweet_embed')).getPropertyValue('height'))
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
}

.tweet_embed {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 80px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tweet_embed">
    <div>Tweet - originally too big, scaled to 50%</div>
    <small>Variable height, loaded by external js.</small>
  </div>
  <div>There's too much white space above this text</div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to simulate a scale effect, the main three things `transform:scale` change is `width`/`height`/`font-size` (margin, padding and more, but if it doesn't effect the visualiztion, doesn't need to specify it.

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
}

.tweet_embed {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: calc(80px / 2);
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="tweet_embed">
    <div>Tweet - originally too big, scaled to 50%</div>
    <small>Variable height, loaded by external js.</small>
  </div>
  <div>There's too much white space above this text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it's only visual, that's why I want to cut the content of the div in half as well, to adjust for it. The height needs to be 50% of the original. It works with absolute numbers but not percentages. And I can't even use JS because I don't know when the tweet will be fully loaded. :/

Comment: @Noximo, you could use js to get screen width and set the actual px for it, will you be ok with it?

Comment: I would but as I said, I don't know when the external JS is done with loading all the required parts of the tweet.
I tried to watch for DOM changes, but then loaded image or applied css aren't DOM changes and yet change the size rapidly.